# Page viewer webpart (set to network folder) works in ie11...but not ie9

Tags: 2010, page-viewer-web-part

I have configured a pvwp to point to a network folder on my app sever.

Any user running ie 11 who opens the page containing the webpart can see the contents of the shared folder.

Any user running ie 9 who opens the page containing the webpart sees a browsers error saying: Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage.
If I have a user with IE 9 log in to sharepoint using a PC running IE 11 they are then able to see the content so it does not appear to be user permissions (in sharepoint or on the share) related.

Does anyone have any ideas on this?

Thank you!

Comment: You should tag related version of SharePoint.

Comment: I tried to define "SharePoint 2010" as a tag prior and the site threw an error. I have now appended it with 2010.  Did you have any suggestions about my issue?